# The number of orderings of elements with order-of-appearance constraints

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider $(q_1,q_2,...) \in Q$ non-intersecting sets of distinct elements $(e_{(i,1)},e_{(i,2)},...)\in q_i$.

How many ways can one write down an ordering of all of the $\sum_j |q_j|$ elements s.t.:

(1) For any two elements $e_{(a,1)}$ & $e_{(b,1)}$, where $a < b$, it must be the case that $e_{(a,1)}$ comes before $e_{(b,1)}$ in the ordering;

(2) For any two elements $e_{(i,a)}$ & $e_{(i,b)}$, where $a < b$, and for any set $q_i$, it must be the case that $e_{(i,a)}$ comes before $e_{(i,b)}$ in the ordering;

Is there a closed-form expression for this count?

For example, if there are only two sets $q_1$ and $q_2$, each with three elements, one possible ordering could be:  $(e_{(1,1)},e_{(1,2)},e_{(2,1)},e_{(2,2)},e_{(1,3)},e_{(2,3)})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your ordering defines a partial order on $Q$ which has a tree as its Hasse diagram. The number you are trying to calculate is the number of [linear extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension) of this poset, or in other words the number of increasing labelings of your tree.

When the Hasse diagram is a forest, this calculation is given by Knuth's hook length formula. There is even a q-analogue by Bjorner and Wachs. For your example the formula gives
$$\frac{1}{\prod_{k\geq 1}(\sum_{i\geq k} |q_i|)}\frac{\left(\sum_i |q_i|\right)!}{\prod_i (|q_i|-1)!}.$$

Comment: I understand the RHS fraction as $|V|!$ over the product of the length of the "hooks" corresponding to each $e_{(i,1)}$, however, what does the LHS term correspond to with respect to the hook length formula?

Comment: That's a single number. I wrote it as a product of two fractions to illustrate separately the ancestors of the nodes $e_{i,1}$ vs ancestors of other nodes.

Comment: That was silly of me.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.